# IN and OUT macros in minwindef.h

Tags: c++, visual-c++

These are defined in minwindef.h (which is often located at Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\minwindef.h)

```
#ifndef IN
#define IN
#endif

#ifndef OUT
#define OUT
#endif
```

And I often see parameters decorated with these macros like this:

```
void SomeFunction(IN const MyClass& obj)
```

What is the significance of these macros and why one should decorate parameters with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These macros may be defined as nothing for compatibility with Standard C and Standard
C++ or they can be defined as MS-specific [SAL (Microsoft source code annotation language) annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402.aspx)
for [Annotating Function Parameters and Return Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh916382.aspx), e.g.

```
#define IN _In_
#define OUT _Out_
```

with the documented meanings:

> _In_
>
> Annotates input parameters that are scalars, structures, pointers to structures and the like. Explicitly may be used on simple scalars. The parameter must be valid in pre-state and will not be modified.
>
> _Out_
>
> Annotates output parameters that are scalars, structures, pointers to structures and the like. Do not apply this to an object that cannot return a value—for example, a scalar that's passed by value. The parameter does not have to be valid in pre-state but must be valid in post-state.

SAL annotations are parsed by MS compilers, of course. MSDN Windows API documentation
employs the SAL annotations, [for example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from their definitions, these macros have no functional use whatsoever.

They are used there only for documentation purposes, to indicate that the function's logical semantics expect, for example, `obj` to be an "in" parameter, as opposed to [an "out" parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6900223/560648).

[C# has actual keywords `in` and `out`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee332485.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), so it's possible that the Windows code includes these equivalents for "consistency" … though, personally, I think having "equivalents" that actually don't do anything, likely does more harm than good.

But, hey, you're the one who works for Microsoft, so perhaps *you* can tell *us*. :)

Comment: They were there long before C# was a twinkle in Anders Hejlsberg's eye. They're actually part of Microsoft's static source code annotation language, but they are defined to no-ops for compatibility reasons when you're not using that analyzer.