# Writing to a file from a kernel module

Tags: c, file, module, kernel

I need to implement the following function as part of a kernel module:

```
ssize_t write(struct file *filp, const char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
```

which writes buf into the file filp using f_pos, and then updates f_pos.

my question is how can I write to f_pos and then change it's value?

I understand that it points to the start of the free file space but how can I update it after i'm done writing?

Thank you

Comment: "how can I update it after i'm done writing?" - Get current position: `loff_t pos=*f_pos;`, modify it (e.g increment by 25): `pos += 25;`, store resulted position to the output parameter: `*f_pos = pos;`. The shorter form of all 3 operations above: `(*f_pos)+=25;`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev since when is it possible to change values of function parameters?

Comment: `f_pos` is an **Input/Output** parameter passed by the pointer. So it is intended to write the resulted value. You probably want to read about "output parameters". See e.g. that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900035/in-out-parameters-and-how-to-work-with-them-in-c

Comment: @Tsyvarev ok I get it, should I also use it to write the data or is the old school way using filp->f_pos preferable?

Comment: You shouldn't use `filp->f_pos` in `write` function. In some cases - when your function is called for `write` syscall - `f_pos` parameter would point to that field. In other cases - `pwrite` syscall - value pointer by `f_pos` corresponds to the parameter of the syscall, and may differ from `filp->f_pos`.