# What are IN, OUT and IN/OUT Parameters Modes in C++

Tags: c++, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

- What is an IN (Incoming Parameter)?
- What is an OUT (Outgoing Parameter)?

... and more.

> Was scrolling through Stack Overflow and found a question similar to
> this. It  was later deleted by the author. There is no searchable
> information on the web  about this. Found a small post read and tried
> to understand. This Q&A is what  is understood from that post and help
> others who might come across this topic.  The aim here is to collate
> some of the more important points for posterity.

Comment: Where do those terms come from? I googled `Incoming Parameter` and `Outgoing Parameter` but nothing useful. It seems the terms you mentioned are rarely used.

Comment: I read that from a question asked at stack overflow. Just learned that it is rather referred as ```IN```, ```OUT``` and ```IN|OUT```. @LouisGo

Comment: @LouisGo Simliar terms are actually mentioned in the [cpp-core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-in), but you're right, ouside of this document they are rarely - if ever - used.

Comment: @churill Your link leades to F.16 "For “in” parameters...." where F.16 and F.17 mention "in" and "out". However I found no "incoming" or "outcoming" in the link. Or maybe "in" and "out" are abbreviation of "incoming" and "outcoming"?

Comment: @LouisGo `[…]The term parameter (sometimes called formal parameter) is often used to refer to the variable as found in the function definition, while argument (sometimes called actual parameter) refers to the actual input supplied at function call.[…]` that quote is from Wikipedia, but also matches other sources.

Comment: Read [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), the official C++11 standard. It has a terminological section

Comment: @LouisGo Yes, I think so. incoming = in and outgoing = out. Both describe the flow of data.

Comment: You should not mix multiple questions in one. `How are they different from Actual and Formal parameters?` in combination with `Incoming/Outgoing Parameter` does not make much sense, as `Actual`/`Formal` are just another name for `argument`/`parameter`, and has nothing to to with incoming or outgoing.

Comment: More details please?

Comment: @Thomas Question isn't to looking for an error or an unknown behavior rather a theoretical answer on concept of parameters. As per my knowledge the details are enough. It would be a pleasure if you specify what kind details you need and leave a link on how I can improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These terms are used to define what kind of operation the function performs on the passed variables. Read, Write or Read/Write. This notation is used in the documentation of libraries to ensure the caller provides appropriate variable type to the function for performing appropriately and not accidentally hinder the output or operation.

IN, OUT and IN/OUT are not C++ keywords, This mode is used in the documentation for just an indication what type of parameter is ideal to pass.

## IN (Incoming Parameters) :

Means that the interface will only read the value. If the parameter is passed by value, it is okay not passing variable as const as the function will have a local variable to perform operations. To avoid copying, passing by reference is preferred, therefore it is recommended to use const to prevent any changes.

## OUT (Outgoing Parameters) :

When the parameter is marked as out, it means that the function does not require to read the value, parameter value is of no importance. In fact the parameters marked are needed to output multiple values. Such parameters are needed to be pointers, references and structures.

## IN/OUT

When the parameter mode is IN/OUT, it signals that the function requires the value passed in the parameter, read the value, then later modify it. Function requires both input and output values.

#### Why are these notation necessary?

These notations help C++ programmers to write simpler, more efficient, more maintainable code. Also help programmers be more specific passing values to the functions to prevent unknown behavior. Usually found when working with open source libraries or external libraries.

For best practices on passing variable when such noataion occurs read more on [CPP Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c-core-guidelines). It deeply explains what to pass to a function in such cases to increase efficiency of the code executed.

#### Refrences :

1. [CPP Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-in)
2. [Programmer Sought](https://www.programmersought.com/article/42064636997/)

Comment: _Technically_ `num2` doesn't change, but the value it was pointing to changes. If instead you were trying to modify `num2 = num3` nothing observable would happen outside the function. Also there are some other questions on this, though it's more referred to as "in / out": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900035/in-out-parameters-and-how-to-work-with-them-in-c