# Why are there [in]'s in the function protoype of HINTERNET?

Tags: c++, c

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetopena#remarks

In looking at some of the Microsoft documentation I noticed the function below

```
HINTERNET InternetOpenA(
  [in] LPCSTR lpszAgent,
  [in] DWORD  dwAccessType,
  [in] LPCSTR lpszProxy,
  [in] LPCSTR lpszProxyBypass,
  [in] DWORD  dwFlags
);
```

The second column is the type and the third a placeholder name. If anyone could explain why the [in]'s are in the first column that would be great. Are they strictly required in the function prototype?

Comment: It's an msvc extension to document whether a parameter is an input, output or both

Comment: That's just the *documentation*. Did you look at the code?

Comment: See [IN/OUT Parameters and how to work with them in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900035/in-out-parameters-and-how-to-work-with-them-in-c)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Alan and link j6t!